# postgresql trigger - Instead of insert dont work

Tags: postgresql

This code works:

```
CREATE TRIGGER HandleRegistration 
    BEFORE INSERT ON Registered 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE registration_handler();
```

But this one does not

```
CREATE TRIGGER HandleRegistration 
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Registered 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE registration_handler();
```

I get the error:

> "registered" is a table" - detail: Tables cannot have INSTEAD OF triggers.

But I have seen plenty examples online that this work. Why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html only for views, also unrelated probably, but `"Registered"` <>`Registered`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

> Triggers that are specified to fire INSTEAD OF the trigger event must
>   be marked FOR EACH ROW, and can only be defined on views.

what you probably are looking for is `RULE`, not `TRIGGER`?..

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrule.html

> Alternatively, an INSTEAD rule can replace a given command by another,
>   or cause a command not to be executed at all.